# How to set up animated drawable with recyclerview?

Tags: android, animation, drawable

Hello all I successfully set up a recycler view an implemented a thumb up function. I also set up a animation for the drawable. When a user gives something a thumb up an animation is displayed and the drawable is filled. I also set up a reverse animation to unfill the drawable. When I fetch data for the recyclerview I´m working with states. If the state is 0 the drawable is unfilled if its 1 its filled.
My drawable is a drawable state list. My issue is when the data is loaded it shows the animation so I tried it with replacing the drawable state list with only a filled or unfilled drawable on start and when the user gets an item a thumb up I replace it with the drawable state list and set a state for that. The problem with that sometimes it didn´t animate the drawable.
I have the same issue in a detail fragment of the recycler items sometimes it changes spontaneously the state of the drawable. What would be the best solution for a drawable with different states in recycler view.
Would be thankful for any answers.

**The drawable state list:**

```
<!-- provide a different drawable for each state-->
<item
    android:id="@+id/state_off"
    android:drawable="@drawable/ic_herzspaceliked"
    android:state_activated="false"
    />
<item
    android:id="@+id/state_on"
    android:drawable="@drawable/heartfill"
    android:state_activated="true"
    />

<transition
    android:drawable="@drawable/heartfill"
    android:fromId="@id/state_off"
    android:toId="@id/state_on"
    android:reversible="true"
    />


<!-- specify transitions -->
```

**How I set the drawable state in recylcerview:**

```
              ((Eventholder)holder).likestate = Objects.requireNonNull(getItem(position)).getUserLikedState();
                if (((Eventholder)holder).likestate== 0) {
                    //((Eventholder)holder).eventCardviewBinding.likebutton.getBackground().setState(new int[]{-android.R.attr.state_activated});
                    ((Eventholder)holder).eventCardviewBinding.likebutton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_herzspaceliked);
                } else if (((Eventholder)holder).likestate==1) {
                    ((Eventholder)holder).eventCardviewBinding.likebutton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_herzliked);
                    //((Eventholder) holder).eventCardviewBinding.likebutton.getBackground().setState(new int[]{android.R.attr.state_activated});
                }
              
                    ((Eventholder)holder).eventCardviewBinding.likebutton.setOnClickListener(v -> {
                if (((Eventholder)holder).likestate==0) {
                    ((Eventholder)holder).likestate=1;
                    ((Eventholder)holder).eventCardviewBinding.likebutton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.heartanimation);
                    ((Eventholder)holder).eventCardviewBinding.likebutton.setActivated(true);
                    ((Eventholder) holder).eventCardviewBinding.LikeCount.setText(String.valueOf(Integer.parseInt(((Eventholder) holder).eventCardviewBinding.LikeCount.getText().toString()) + 1));
                }
                else if (((Eventholder)holder).likestate==1) {
                    ((Eventholder)holder).likestate=0;
                    ((Eventholder)holder).eventCardviewBinding.likebutton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.heartanimation);
                    ((Eventholder)holder).eventCardviewBinding.likebutton.setActivated(false);
                    ((Eventholder) holder).eventCardviewBinding.LikeCount.setText(String.valueOf(Integer.parseInt(((Eventholder) holder).eventCardviewBinding.LikeCount.getText().toString()) -1 ));
                }
                itemClickHandler.likestate(getItem(position));
            });
```

**How I set up the drawable state list in details fragment:**

```
  public void ButtonUI()
{
    //LikeButton
    binding.likeButtonholder.setOnClickListener(v -> {
        if (likestate==0)
            likestate=1;
        else
            likestate=0;

        mainViewModel.init(firebaseAuth.getUid(),Events.getId(),Events.getEventName(),Events.getArt(),Events.getGENRE());
        mainViewModel.getLikeStateLiveData().observe(getViewLifecycleOwner(), state -> {
            if (state==1){
                Events.setUserLikedState(1);
                binding.likeButtonholder.setSelected(true);
                binding.likecounter.setText(String.valueOf((Events.getLikes()) + 1));
                Events.setLikes(Events.getLikes() + 1);
            }
            else if (state==0){
                //binding.likeButtonholder.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.white_heartanimation);
                binding.likeButtonholder.setSelected(false);
                binding.likecounter.setText(String.valueOf((Events.getLikes()) - 1));
                Events.setUserLikedState(0);
                Events.setLikes(Events.getLikes() - 1);
            }
            else
                Toast.makeText(getContext(),"Error",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        });
    });
}
 public void Observe()
{
    //AccountData
    //EventDetailsData
    viewModel.getEvents().observe(getViewLifecycleOwner(), events -> {

      
        Events=events;
        likestate=events.getUserLikedState();
        if (likestate==0) {
            binding.likeButtonholder.getBackground().setState(new int[]{-android.R.attr.state_selected});
        }
        else
            binding.likeButtonholder.getBackground().setState(new int[]{android.R.attr.state_selected});
)};
}
```

Comment: At the end of your `onBindViewHolder` try adding `likebutton.jumpDrawablesToCurrentState()`.

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer unfortunately it don´t work. When I scroll down the drawable animate to the current state but I only need the animation when the button is clicked not when the drawables are loaded.

Comment: I think its beacause I set the states programmatically and when the items are rendered the animation starts but after weeks of searching I didn´t find a better solution for that

Comment: Generally you shouldn't inject states into background drawables as they are set by view that contains them (so your injected state might get overwritten). Maybe remove your weird workaround of swapping drawables first (so it's always animated state drawable), your bindviewholder should be as simple as `likebutton.setActivated(likestate == 0)` and `likebutton.jumpDrawablesToCurrentState()`.

Comment: Thank you! It works fine but I think I got a issue in my drawable state list. When an item is activated and the drawable is filled I got the reverse animation to unfilled on click but when clicked again it shows the unfilled animation again and nothing else. So when the state is activated and I set it to unfilled the reverse animation is the only one displayed for that item after that. I tried different things but nothing worked. I post a own answer for that problem if you got some time I would be thankful if you could take a look at it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem by adding an animated drawable also as state_off drawable!

```
<animated-selector
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<!-- provide a different drawable for each state-->

<item
    android:id="@+id/state_on"
    android:drawable="@drawable/heartfill"
    android:state_selected="true"
    />

<item
    android:id="@+id/state_off"
    android:drawable="@drawable/heart_unfill"
    />

<transition
    android:drawable="@drawable/heartfill"
    android:fromId="@id/state_off"
    android:toId="@id/state_on"
    />
<transition
    android:drawable="@drawable/heart_unfill"
    android:fromId="@id/state_on"
    android:toId="@id/state_off"
    />
<!-- specify transitions -->
```

Thats the right way.
Also changed my code as Pawel told me:

```
((Eventholder)holder).likestate=Objects.requireNonNull(getItem(position)).getUserLikedState();
            ((Eventholder)holder).eventCardviewBinding.likebutton.setSelected((((Eventholder)holder).likestate==1));
            ((Eventholder)holder).eventCardviewBinding.likebutton.jumpDrawablesToCurrentState();
            
                    ((Eventholder)holder).eventCardviewBinding.likebutton.setOnClickListener(v -> {
                if (((Eventholder)holder).likestate==1) {
                    ((Eventholder)holder).likestate=0;
                    ((Eventholder) holder).eventCardviewBinding.LikeCount.setText(String.valueOf(Integer.parseInt(((Eventholder) holder).eventCardviewBinding.LikeCount.getText().toString()) -1 ));
                }
                else {
                    ((Eventholder)holder).likestate=1;
                    ((Eventholder) holder).eventCardviewBinding.LikeCount.setText(String.valueOf(Integer.parseInt(((Eventholder) holder).eventCardviewBinding.LikeCount.getText().toString()) + 1));
                }
                ((Eventholder)holder).eventCardviewBinding.likebutton.setSelected(((Eventholder)holder).likestate==1);
                itemClickHandler.likestate(getItem(position));
            });
```